# Tables push text off page. Why?

Tags: tables, floats

My floating tables push down the text so far that it is cut off by the end of the page. Why is that? Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,skip=0.9cm]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{W destinatum ullatenus id vel oppressa te obcaecati miscere \label{reductive_reasoning}}
    \begin{longtable}[]{@{}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 2\tabcolsep) * \real{0.4}}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 2\tabcolsep) * \real{0.4}}@{}}
        \toprule
        Alice                                                 & Bob            \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \(p\)                                                 & \(p?\)         \\
        \(\{p_{1,a,1},...,p_{1,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p\)         & \(p_{1,a,1}?\) \\
        \(\{p_{2,a,1},...,p_{2,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{1,a,1}\) &
        \(p_{2,a,1}?\)                                                         \\
        \(\{p_{3,a,1},...,p_{3,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{2,a,1}\) &
        \(p_{3,a,1}?\)                                                         \\
        \ldots{}                                              &                \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{table}

Se ornare ullo discrimen parmensis congue id vel quasi si y
circumventus, ad lacus esse in nomina ea sem metus est itineribus et
utraque decembris est sacrilegum ante ea est arripio sem hostem ea hic
natus uidem leo intaminata ut sunt quos exaudire.
Ac ornare nisi provident perversis orbare id hic metus te s
adlaborabunt, eu arcui eros mi labore ad non minus dui placentini ut
nostrae prophetas dui periculose modi ac dui ambulat rem mentes ad est
dolor mirum dui consiliori in eget quam germania.

Suspicio a odio vel dispendio respirium discursus mi alliciebat id
apparet parmensis, li ut leo liber. Sed morsum te metus odit vicissim me
Nulla. Ante amet ita dis quas ad hac quo quos ea Nam, risus ut
necessitate te hic progredi. Patitur, il at fretus per, dennuntio,
invita si contraxit Optio. Pharetra, uidem Non pede tacere potiorue quas
odio indago ``Quo?'' sit hic nisl nec arcu quasi natus ab martii, ti ut
arcu nemo dui vel mi ``est dui utrumque'' me excessivos nisi duis magnam
ea typi Totam nemo est et possujnus. Respectum, hendrerit possujnus mi
piscatores et gubernia eu verius per hac usus praetorito te ``perltum
dui imponere'' eget ultimae dui fuga colligati laedit.

Ad decessu autem utramque, O commodo m tincidunt commodum ipsum M ille
mirum id eu \modo{sequentia mandata}. Caedis sunt per netus ultimum ita
est sensus ut metus enim vel class, sunt raritas eodem est perare
ripensi ea quia culpa convaluit id iure autem at habent peregrina
troiano est lacinia ipsa ab hic assum nisi. Sed locorum quaedam modo ex
unde eu nec in leo gothica maiores tot auctores id vel laedit sociosqu.
Mus sunt ut cumulabat scelera in debilitatem si liber
\ref{reductive_arguing}.

\begin{table}
    \caption{W destinatum ullatenus id vel oppressa te obcaecati miscere \label{reductive_arguing}}
    \begin{longtable}[]{@{}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 2\tabcolsep) * \real{0.4}}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 2\tabcolsep) * \real{0.4}}@{}}
        \toprule
        \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\raggedright
            Alice
        \end{minipage}                 & \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\raggedright
                                             Bob
                                         \end{minipage}                                       \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \(p\)                                                       & \(\{p_{1,b,1},...,p_{1,b,n}\} \Rightarrow \lnot p\) \\
        \(\{p_{2,a,1},...,p_{2,a,n}\} \Rightarrow \lnot p_{1,b,1}\) &
        \(\{p_{3,b,1},...,p_{3,b,n}\} \Rightarrow \lnot p_{2,a,1}\)                                                       \\
        \(\{p_{4,a,1},...,p_{4,a,n}\} \Rightarrow \lnot p_{3,b,1}\) &
        \(\{p_{5,b,1},...,p_{5,b,n}\} \Rightarrow \lnot p_{4,a,1}\)                                                       \\
        \(\{p_{6,a,1},...,p_{6,a,n}\} \Rightarrow \lnot p_{5,b,1}\) &
        \(\{p_{7,b,1},...,p_{7,b,n}\} \Rightarrow \lnot p_{6,a,1}\)                                                       \\
        \ldots{}                                                    &                                                     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{table}
Ac pede vincere urna Animi eos Cum bibendum et defensive mandata in hic
laborans vincere. Hac nicolae omnis gentes ti at vel lorem dis
\emph{ultricies}. Per indolem ipsa id silentium in amet nisi doloribus
euismod ipsa e personami iste o \emph{politius} vestrorum. Opiniones
scelera te urna arenam at auctores ab surdis eum versus ut d domesticas
typi ultrices raritas fusce diam quas in est odio unde wisi proditorem
subiungam ii enim eius te ``hic est sangvine''. Ab gentes septembris
similique ripensi odit fuga at symbolum mus ex nicolae gratitudinis est
cursum te mirum, absentiam quaerat decima dis desertor si deplorata
meruerunt. Ex nec servata monoculus ab massa te provident symbola typi
qui ultricies duis.

\end{document}
```

Please ignore the other formatting issues with this example, since the code is adapted from a thesis in which additional settings prevent these issues from appearing. I am only interested in understanding the reason for the cut off text.

Comment: Why are you using `longtable` inside a `table` environment?

Comment: Welcome! The only scope of `longtable` is to break across pages, and floats (like `table`) can't be broken across pages. You either use a `tabular` inside your float environment, or use a `longtable` alone.

Comment: @egreg Those `longtable`s had originally been created by pandoc. I was putting them into floats without considering the subleties @Rmano thankfully pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @egreg and @Rmano, you are not supposed to use a `longtable` inside a `table` environment. Changing the occurences of `longtable` to `tabular` and `centering` them sets the same tables without pushing the text off the page.

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{W destinatum ullatenus id vel oppressa te obcaecati miscere \label{reductive_reasoning}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[]{@{}
        % stuff
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly off-topic ...

- As was already mentioned, long tables had not be enclosed in float environment. It prevent that long tables can be broken between pages and consequently they spill out at bottom page.
- If you willing to consider to use `longtabular` package for writing your (long) tables, you will have les problems at defining column widths as well to put columns in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{caption}
\newcommand\modo[1]{\textbf{\emph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption={W destinatum ullatenus id vel oppressa te obcaecati miscere},
  label={reductive_reasoning}
                    ]{%
        colspec={@{} *2{X[l,mode=math]} @{}},
        row{1} = {mode=text},
        rowhead=1
             }
    \toprule
Alice   & Bob               \\
    \midrule
p       &   p?              \\
\{p_{1,a,1},...,p_{1,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p
        &   p_{1,a,1}?      \\
\{p_{2,a,1},...,p_{2,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{1,a,1}
        &   p_{2,a,1}?      \\
\{p_{3,a,1},...,p_{3,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{2,a,1}
        &   p_{3,a,1}?      \\
\{p_{4,a,1},...,p_{4,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{3,a,1}
        &   p_{4,a,1}?      \\
\ldots  &                   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
    
Se ornare ullo discrimen parmensis congue id vel quasi si y circumventus, ad lacus esse in nomina ea sem metus est itineribus et utraque decembris est sacrilegum ante ea est arripio sem hostem ea hic natus uidem leo intaminata ut sunt quos exaudire. Ac ornare nisi provident perversis orbare id hic metus te s adlaborabunt, eu arcui eros mi labore ad non minus dui placentini ut nostrae prophetas dui periculose modi ac dui ambulat rem mentes ad est dolor mirum dui consiliori in eget quam germania.

Suspicio a odio vel dispendio respirium discursus mi alliciebat id apparet parmensis, li ut leo liber. Sed morsum te metus odit vicissim me Nulla. Ante amet ita dis quas ad hac quo quos ea Nam, risus ut necessitate te hic progredi. Patitur, il at fretus per, dennuntio, invita si contraxit Optio. Pharetra, uidem Non pede tacere potiorue quas odio indago ``Quo?'' sit hic nisl nec arcu quasi natus ab martii, ti ut arcu nemo dui vel mi ``est dui utrumque'' me excessivos nisi duis magnam ea typi Totam nemo est et possujnus. Respectum, hendrerit possujnus mi piscatores et gubernia eu verius per hac usus praetorito te ``perltum dui imponere'' eget ultimae dui fuga colligati laedit.

Ad decessu autem utramque, O commodo m tincidunt commodum ipsum Mille mirum id eu \modo{sequentia mandata}. Caedis sunt per netus ultimum ita est sensus ut metus enim vel class, sunt raritas eodem est perare ripensi ea quia culpa convaluit id iure autem at habent peregrina troiano est lacinia ipsa ab hic assum nisi. Sed locorum quaedam modo ex unde eu nec in leo gothica maiores tot auctores id vel laedit sociosqu. Mus sunt ut cumulabat scelera in debilitatem si liber \ref{reductive_arguing}.

    \begin{longtblr}[
caption={W destinatum ullatenus id vel oppressa te obcaecati miscere},
  label={reductive_arguing}
                    ]{%
        colspec={@{} *2{X[l,mode=math]} @{}},
        row{1} = {mode=text},
        rowhead=1
             }
    \toprule
Alice   & Bob               \\
    \midrule
p       &   p?              \\
\{p_{1,a,1},...,p_{1,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p
        &   p_{1,a,1}?      \\
\{p_{2,a,1},...,p_{2,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{1,a,1}
        &   p_{2,a,1}?      \\
\{p_{3,a,1},...,p_{3,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{2,a,1}
        &   p_{3,a,1}?      \\
\{p_{4,a,1},...,p_{4,a,n}\} \Rightarrow p_{3,a,1}
        &   p_{4,a,1}?      \\
\ldots  &                   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}

Ac pede vincere urna Animi eos Cum bibendum et defensive mandata in hic laborans vincere. Hac nicolae omnis gentes ti at vel lorem dis \emph{ultricies}. Per indolem ipsa id silentium in amet nisi doloribus euismod ipsa e personami iste o \emph{politius} vestrorum. Opiniones scelera te urna arenam at auctores ab surdis eum versus ut d domesticas typi ultrices raritas fusce diam quas in est odio unde wisi proditorem subiungam ii enim eius te ``hic est sangvine''. Ab gentes septembris similique ripensi odit fuga at symbolum mus ex nicolae gratitudinis est cursum te mirum, absentiam quaerat decima dis desertor si deplorata meruerunt. Ex nec servata monoculus ab massa te provident symbola typi qui ultricies duis.

\end{document}
```

[image]